# Передача данных из БД в функцию Django

Tags: python, django, база-данных

Я хотел бы получать данные из БД, подставлять их в API запрос и размещать результат на странице. Есть БД, в ней есть поля серия и номер паспорта. Хотелось бы реализовать функционал подстановки серии и номера паспорта в функцию, которая производит API запрос к серверу.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
class client(models.Model):
    family = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=25)
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=25)
    patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length=25)
    serial = models.CharField('Серия паспорта', max_length=25)
    number = models.CharField('Номер паспорта', max_length=25)
```

jsonparse.py

```
import requests

def parsej(x, y):
    URL = "url"
    headers_auth = {
        "serial": x,
        "number": y
    }
    result = requests.post(URL, json=headers_auth)
    content = result.json()
    
    return content

print(parsej('53 03', '244787'))
```

Как передать значение из БД SQlite в функцию Python?

Comment: Сложно помочь не зная примерную структуру проекта. Что у вас уже есть? Как работаете с БД? Как будете работать с программой (через консоль или это какое-то клиент-серверное приложение)? Обычно результаты работы одна функция передает другой вызывая эту ф-ю с параметрами. Но мне кажется начать нужно с вопросов выше. Тогда и разберемся.

Comment: С БД как и с программой работаю через Django. Это всё будет происходить на сайте, заранее спасибо

Comment: *которая производит API запрос к серверу* -  а какому серверу производит запрос? Правильно ли я понял что запрос производится к внешнему источнику данных, у которого есть свой API?

Comment: Скрипт запроса к серверу разместил в вопросе. Вместо x и y в функции нужно подставить серию и номер паспорта из бд

Comment: Подскажите, по адресу который вы указали в вопросе, уже размещён готовый Djanjo API ? Если да, добавьте код, что бы можно было понять чем вам помочь. Но как я понял из вашего вопроса, вам нужно сделать апи допустим на drf (тут будут модели, сериалайзер и т.д.) после чего вы сможете отправлят запросы на запись, то есть использовать стандартную ORM django

Comment: К сожалению у меня нет кода стороны сервера. Я лишь знаю запрос который необходимо отправить, для получения ответа от сервера. После того как запрос доставлен на сервер, от него приходит ответ. Запрос строго по форме указанной в переменной headers_auth. API открыто в тестовом режиме, поэтому для получения ответа вместо "x" нужно подставить 53 03 (учитывая пробел), а вместо "y" 244787.

Comment: @ИванКуликов, покажите пожалуйста код models.py

Comment: @АндрейКоробейников, дополнил вопрос файлом models.py

Comment: @ИванКуликов, ну все верно. Пробовали мое решение? если есть по нему вопросы - там в комментариях пишите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если django то у вас должен быть файл views.py в котором вы создаете функции контроллеры для обращения к БД за данными и к внешним источникам. Таким образом вы можете написать примерно следующее, предполагая что parsej у вас в файле utils.py в каталоге с models.py и views.py данного приложения django

```py
# views.py

from .utils import parsej

def get_data(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        passport_info = client.objects.get(1)
        result = parsej(x=passport_info.serial, y=passport_info.number)
        # обработка результата
        context = {"passport_info":passport_info, "result": result}
        return render(request, "app/view_info_by_passport.html", context=context)
```

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import get_data

urlpatterns = [
    path('', get_data, name="get_data"),
    ...
]
```

```html
<!-- view_info_by_passport.html -->

<html>
<body>
<h3>{{passport_info.serial}} {{passport_info.number}}</h3>
{{result}}
</body>
</html>
```

Так же возможно на странице нужно будет выбирать конкретного человека из списка или в функции get_data проверять авторизацию пользователя и для него запрашивать данные с сервера API, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Выдает ошибку: cannot unpack non-iterable int object. В строчке рендера нужно прописать наименование приложения и шаблона по маске которую вы указали?

Comment: Немного изменил, что бы ясней было, там где app - название вашего приложения впишите.  у вас уже есть шаблоны других страниц? Возможно вам нужно углубить в изучение django для продолжения работы над своим проектом?

Comment: это точно, займусь в самое ближайшее время. А вам - огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @ИванКуликов, не за что. Вливайтесь ) Если вам подходит этот ответ, то можете пометить его как решение.

Comment: cannot unpack non-iterable int object может подскажете с чем связана данная ошибка?))

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том что *там где должен быть итерируемый объект (словарь, список, кортеж...) передается int*. И программа не может распаковать данный объект. Это я в коде ошибся в строке `passport_info = client.objects.get(1)` -> `passport_info = client.objects.get(id=1)`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!!!